# Regex not working(newline)

Tags: regex, vb.net

This is my last resort. Please Help.

Source:

```
    <div class="custom">
    <div class="presence">Eating</div>
```

Code that is not working:

```
Dim code As String = "\s*<div class=""custom"">""\n""\s*<div class=""presence"">.*</div>"

    Dim reg As New Regex(code)
    If reg.IsMatch(RichTextBox1.Text) Then
        MsgBox("h")
    End If
```

Comment: What is not working? What is happening, and what do you want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\s` is enough to parse any white-space characters including new line characters:

```
Dim code As String = "\s*<div class=""custom"">\s*<div class=""presence"">.*</div>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `\r\n` instead of `\n`